# How can i hide powered by?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="isd-powered-by" ng-show="showBranding">
        <a href="http://www.inksoft.com" target="_blank"><span>Powered by</span> <img ng-src="//images.inksoft.com/designer/html5/ds/images/footer-logo.png" alt="" src="//images.inksoft.com/designer/html5/ds/images/footer-logo.png"></a>
      </div>
```

How can i hide this?

I tried this in embedded code they provided.

```
<div class="isd-powered-by" ng-show="showBranding">
<label>Question? </label>
Nein
</div>

<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("isd-powered-by")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

Comment: It's not really nice to do that to something that isn't your product

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<style>
.isd-powered-by {
   display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

also I have to agree with @Sterling, it is not nice